# How to prioritize terraform execution priority

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

After rds and elastic cache are created in terraform, 
I would like to adjust the priority so that ec2 is set up.

Is this feasible with terraform?

to be precise, I am running docker on ec2. I would like to pass the endpoint of elastic cache, RDS created by terraform to docker with environment variables.

Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is feasible with terraform's [Implicit and Explicit Dependencies](https://www.terraform.io/intro/getting-started/dependencies.html#implicit-and-explicit-dependencies).

So, you can define which resource should be created first and which one is after.

It is supported by the following construction, which takes list of resources:

```
  depends_on = [
    "", "",
]
```

Here is an example:

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "rds_example" {
  allocated_storage    = 10
  storage_type         = "gp2"
  engine               = "mysql"
  engine_version       = "5.6.17"
  instance_class       = "db.t1.micro"
  name                 = "mydb"
  username             = "foo"
  password             = "bar"
  db_subnet_group_name = "my_database_subnet_group"
  parameter_group_name = "default.mysql5.6"
}

resource "aws_instance" "ec2_example" {
  ami           = "${data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id}"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags {
    Name = "HelloWorld"
  }
  depends_on = [
        "aws_db_instance.rds_example",
    ]
}
```

Comment: You should expand on this answer to explain what is meant by _implicit_ and _explicit_ dependencies and include examples directly in the answer rather than leaving all the useful parts of your answer behind a link to another site (even if it is the official docs).

Comment: Fixed. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your commenting. I solved it using "depend_on" option you teach me